# Как отрисовать изображение поверх другого в Java?

Tags: java, awt

Нужно нарисовать в большом изображении (на данный момент это `BufferedImage`) маленькое на определенных координатах. Каким образом это делается (метод для рисования внутри, к примеру) ? Если нужны другой класс изображения/графики - не проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Странно, вроде-бы искать не долго должны были!

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
BufferedImage smallerImage = ...; 
img.getGraphics().drawImage(smallerImage, 100, 100, null);
```

после этого в изображении `img` должно появится изображение `smallerImage`, сдвинутое на 100 пикселей вправо и 100 пикселей вниз

Comment: Бесконечно благодарен! Отдельно встречал и пробовал как getGraphics(), так и drawImage(), но результат ясен